# schema.rb not updating after transfer to a new machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, schema, migration

I transfered a project to a new machine.  Everything works.  I can run migrations and they update the mysql database.  However, the schema.rb file doesn't acknowledge the changes.  I checked the read/write permissions for schema.rb are OK.  Does anyone have any idea about what could cause this problem.  I'm using Rails version 2.3.5.  rake:redo rake:rollback don't work because the schema is not aware of the changes in database.  running rake db:migrate again does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was that I had the following line in my development.rb file

`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`

After commenting it, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have never encountered this problem but this may solve it:

1. Take a backup of your current *schema.rb* `cp db/schema.rb db/schema.rb.backup`
2. Delete *schema.rb* `rm db/schema.rb`
3. Run `rake db:migrate`

This will regenarate your *schema.rb* file from the current database state.